# Declare a unique constraint for Neo4j relationships dependent on direction (ideally with py2neo)

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

Is there an alternative to py2neo's create_unique method for relationships that takes direction into account? Such that uniqueness === same nodes, same label, and same direction?

A solution for Py2neo would be ideal, but I wouldn't be opposed to switching to a more complete driver if there is one.

*EDIT*: seems like it's a functionality that doesn't exist in Cypher in the first place. I still think it would make a useful driver functionality.

*EDIT 2*: Cypher let's me use create_unique with direction:

```
MATCH (b { name: 'Bob' }), (a {name:'Alice'})
CREATE UNIQUE (b)-[r:SWIPED_RIGHT]->(a)
RETURN r
```

Would be lovely to be able to do the same without writing a raw cypher query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in Py2neo all relationship are created "Outgoing". 
Use "http://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html#py2neo.Rev" for "Incoming" relationships.

Example: -
//Creates "Outgoing" Relationship
Relationship(Node("FEMALE",name="A"),"FRIEND",Node("FEMALE",name="B"))

//Creates "Incoming" Relationship
Relationship(Node("FEMALE",name="A"),Rev("FRIEND"),Node("FEMALE",name="B"))

Comment: Sumit is exactly right. Wrapping `Rev` around a relationship will be interpreted by py2neo as a reverse relationship in most contexts.

Comment: Great, I missed that! Haven't done my homework properly.